# What's the difference between using await keyword versus omitting it in an async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

How is using `await` keyword is different than omitting it when you don't capture the return value of the `await` call?

For example, are there any differences in the way these 4 files are created? because if I run this, all 4 of them are created, so I wonder.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

(async function () {
    await writeFile('a.txt', 'aaa');
    await writeFile('b.txt', 'bbb');
    writeFile('c.txt', 'ccc');
    writeFile('d.txt', 'ddd');
})()
```

## Update:

**I tried some tests and it looks like it behaves as answered, but in the end, things got weird.**

So if you run the following,

```
writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
writeFile('a.txt', 'bar');
const content = await readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(content);
```

output is sometimes `foo` and sometimes `bar`, which seems like both `writeFile` calls are fired at the same time and who finishes last depends on luck.

so I changed it to:

```
writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
await writeFile('a.txt', 'bar');
const content = await readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(content);
```

and I thought (based on the answers) that this would always output `bar`, but output again is sometimes `foo` and sometimes `bar`.
I'm not sure I understand, because I thought I awaited the call that writes `bar`, so the only explanation would be that the first `writeFile` call somehow gets its turn after the awaited call.

then I tied to put a delay between the calls:

```
writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
[...Array(400000).fill('hello')].join('\n')
writeFile('a.txt', 'bar');
const content = await readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(content);
```

and this time it always outputs `bar`.

then something weird happened.
if you run the following:

```
writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
[...Array(40000).fill('hello')].join('\n')
writeFile('a.txt', 'b');
const content = await readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(content);
```

the output is `boo`, which the only explanation I can think of is that the first `writeFile` writes `foo` to the file, then second `writeFile` starts to write to the file but before it's finished doing it, the awaited `readFile` reads the file. (LOL)

Comment: @JonasWilms that's why I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample code:

```js
writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
await writeFile('a.txt', 'bar');
const content = await readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(content);
```

The first `writeFile` may complete at any time since it's not being awaited. It doesn't matter if you're waiting for `bar` to be written; that just means your read completes after the second write. The first write may complete after that still. That's why `readFile` could be either `foo` or `bar`.

Maybe it'd help to visualize by showing the equivalent code not expressed as an async function:

```
function doTheThing() {
  writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
  return writeFile('a.txt', 'bar')
    .then(() => {
      // This happened after writing 'bar', but 'foo' may/may not have finished
      return readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
    })
    .then(content => {
      console.log(content);
    });
}
```

This is a so-called race-condition. Think of parallel running tracks:

```
                  File state

writeFile 'foo'               writeFile 'bar'
      |--- A -->                    |
      |              bar <----------|
      |--- B -->                    v
      |--- C -->                readFile
      |                             |
      |               ?  ---------->|
      |                             v
      |                       console.log()
      |--- D -->
```

Because we're not waiting for that first write, it may complete at points A, B, C, D, or never (if it fails or takes forever).

- If it completes at point A, then 'bar' will overwrite 'foo'
- If it completes at point B, then 'foo' will overwrite 'bar'
- If it completes in the middle of the read at point C, you may even read a partial write!

The only way to guarantee a write order is to `await` to keep them in order:

```js
await writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
await writeFile('a.txt', 'bar');
const content = await readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(content); // Always 'bar'
```

For this block of code:

```js
writeFile('a.txt', 'foo');
[...Array(40000).fill('hello')].join('\n')
writeFile('a.txt', 'b');
const content = await readFile('a.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(content);
```

...you are correct that since you are not awaiting `writeFile` in any case, `readFile` may be reading the file in the middle of it being written.

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Answer (score 2):

It just doesn't `await` the result then. It will just *fire & forget* the asynchronous task. Thats not what you want in most cases, as code runs *out of order* and *errors aren't handled*.

```
 await writeFile(); // If an error occurs in writeFile, the promise returned by this function will reject too
 await writeFile(); // this will definetly run after the previous call completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

`await` is required in this case if you are using result value OR if you have to wait until function under `await` being executed.

`await` stops main thread execution till function under `await` returns.

Comment: "stops main thread execution" ... *of the enclosing `async function` only ... Also its questionable wether there is a "main thread" in JS

Comment: It doesn't actually stop the thread, but it makes it seem like it does, since the code after `await` doesn't run until the function completes. That's the point of async/await, it provides this illusion of sequentiality.

Comment: @JonasWilms Can't help but derail a little bit, but what makes you say that there is no main thread? JS is single threaded

Comment: @Barmar `async` functions are fundamentally different entities https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @Andrew I know that, but it simplifies coding because you can ignore the difference to a limited extent.

Comment: @Andrew no, JS has an *observably synchronous execution model*. There are no threads in JS. (There are agents (commonly known as WebWorkers / processes in NodeJS) though)

Comment: @JonasWilms Can you share some type of reference material for this? I am now curious

Comment: @Andrew ES262 spec, somewhere in the first part (search for "Agent")

Comment: @Andrew `await` doesn't "pause" the execution - it works a lot more like `yield` - it will save the function state, and when the promise that is `await`-ed resolves, restores the function and continues execution after the keyword.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. At least in browser. By main thread I meant thread of the async function in which await is used. And in reality it just freezes this execution and returns back to it when await gets returned.

Comment: @vlaz it does pause *the functions* execution. Thats what the spec says.

Comment: @AlexVovchuk no, JS is not single threaded. It can, and does have multiple execution threads (e.g. WebWorkers). The term "Main thread" is coined differently. "it freezes the execution" yes, of the function, not of the thread

Comment: In case someonne wants to read the [relevant spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-agents) (e.g. @Andrew)

Comment: @JonasWilms therefore I've written 'At least in browser', because WebWorkers generate new thread beyond the browser window. Aside of WebWorkers we have only one thread for JS and just jump between asynchronous operations. And freeze in function - is stopping execution of code in it and proceeding in code above.

Comment: @JonasWilms indeed. I wasn't clear there - there was the notion that it paused the *thread* which is not what happens. Indeed, it pauses the function execution. So, `await` doesn't sit and wait halting everything else.

Comment: @AlexVovchuk again that's not quite correct. The "JavaScript is single threaded" is an oversimplification that does more harm than good in the long run. Even without WebWorkers code from different pages in the browser would run on different threads. Well, depends on the browser and it depends on the number of tabs, etc., as a browser might lump few tabs on one thread and not keep a thread per tab. Still, not *all* JS executes on the same thread. Indeed, the browser might also be running JS internally and it would be a separate thread, too.

Comment: @AlexVovchuk if we generalise "JavaScript" has no concept of threads - it's a language that you write instructions for the computer in. It's the environment that decides how to run these. So, a more accurate statement is that *your code* will run on one thread - the main UI one, yet there are exceptions to that, too.